# Vue3 - What is the official replacement for EventBus

Tags: vuejs3

In Vue3, the EventBus has been removed, however the docs suggest using some third party plugins to mimick the functionality (ie, mitt).

However, there is no mention of the 'official' replacement. I looked at provide/inject but that seems to address a different issue (parent talking to deeply nested children only in a one way direction).

You could also use Vuex I suppose, but I wanted to know does Vue3 have a replacement for EventBus? Why even remove it in the first place if not?

Comment: "In Vue 3, it is no longer possible to use these APIs to listen to a component's own emitted events from within a component, there is no migration path for that use case." - https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/migration/events-api.html#migration-strategy

Comment: After posting this question, I saw some code examples on how EASY it is to pass around functions to different components, it makes EventBus almost obsolete. It makes sense they removed it.

Comment: where you find some examples

Comment: They are mostly referred as `composables` (I think thats a word used by the creator of Vue) and are simple functions that you can export and import where you need them.